# React Typescript - Can't stablish type of object well

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

i'm just started learning Typescript. I trying to migrate a project from Javascript, but I got stuck with a custom hook.

The hook, useForm, just handle the onChange event of inputs in a form and then updates their values so I can write in and control their states.

```
interface formProps{
  initialValues: {[key: string]: string}
}

export const useForm = ( initialState: formProps['initialValues'] ) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState);

  const reset = () => {
    setValues(initialState);
  }

  const handleInputChange = ({ target }: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>{
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [target.name]:target.value
    })
  }
  return [values, handleInputChange, reset]
}
```

The argument for useForm should be an object with different entries, but the problem is it could be different any time, so I can't specify this.

When I try to use the hook in a component with for example `values.userID` or `` values['password`] `` I get the error:

> The property 'password' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]:
> string; } | (({ target }: ChangeEvent) => void)'

How could I fix this? Thanks in advance!

**Edit**:
I extract the values from 'values' with:

`const [values, handleInputChange] = useForm({userID: '', password: ''})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working using:

```
import { useState } from "react";

interface InitialStateTypes  {
  [key: string]: string;
}

export const useForm = (initialState: InitialStateTypes): [InitialStateTypes, ({ target }: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void, ()=> void]  => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState);

  const reset = () => {
    setValues(initialState);
  }

  const handleInputChange = ({ target }: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>{
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [target.name]:target.value
    })
  }
  return [values, handleInputChange, reset]
}
```

And I can access the values from 'values' using `values['value']` instead of `values.value`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use generics to type the state according to the initial state, and return an object, so TS can easily infer the types ([TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxLYDCAFigHYDmSAogG5IMwASjAJgBskUGvWZtO3OAF84AMygQQcAORRUGVQG4AsACgDSAB6RYcNBAaF4RJADFoKgLxwAPABU4Jyg36FEJEsofjcbKGBmbHDIpgA+OIAKOEjgGGAUQTIKJAAuOC8ASjhnONwDOAsrGzgAbXZM-CRCaKQYADVG5oBdEoJibMpE1PTMwaRCvUN9SstreA1ieFdE4tLymcq4Jc7BJsJhhjSMrPJKSYrZKcu5mvEhJABJBjB8GDpGFj7EvHIoFngMnyHwkHC4MDcPA8AFkADLPV4wVjCEDguJrMo4S6VHZdA5YzZbOAAOlJDT2zUw2K2tT+AOJDBQqO6uTpbWJ5Ka1JkF02Mmumw0MHwUAYuDgnMpcHuwgRbxBLGwizaVwMMgMBlu8Dwkpa0oEspe8vEXzkrjsjigIB+-REjwAIvlVKpsGAUIRCAB3aD8J2qWS8gy62qqOxQB2qXquVTGHQa-TB1Ruj3ekKRvqqACeOiAA)):

```
import React, { useState, ChangeEventHandler, ChangeEvent } from 'react';

export const useForm = <T extends Record<string, string>>( initialState: T ) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState);

  const reset = () => {
    setValues(initialState);
  };

  const handleInputChange = ({ target }: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [target.name]:target.value
    });
  };

  return { values, handleInputChange, reset };
}

const { values, handleInputChange } = useForm({ userID: '', password: '' });

values['userID'] = 'x';

values['password'] = 'y';
```

Comment: I forgot to say that I use ```const [values, handleInputChange] = useForm({userID: '', password: ''})``` to get the values and handleInputChange, and it seems not work  this way

Comment: Use object destructuring `{ values, handleInputChange }`.